# calling a function on an instance of my jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm new to jQuery. I have a plugin that draws a chart on an html canvas. I'd like to change some chart settings in response what the user selects in some other html controls on the page. I need a way to call a function on my plugin with a new parameter, passing control to the plugin so I can redraw it.

How to I code this function on my plugin?

Thanks,
Gerry

Comment: I answered my own question. By defining a custom event with the jQuery trigger() method, and handling it in my plugin with:. $(this).on({}) I am able to trigger an event with parameters on my plugin. When a control on the page changes, it can send the new parameter to the plugn.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the argument onclick

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: Nope. See my comment above. Thanks.